# Is the purpose of returning None in base case of recursion simply used as a filler, and then naturally the top recursive call in call stack executes?

Tags: python, recursion

I am solving a recursion problem, where I am given an array of integers and asked to return the powerset of it.

e.g. powerset of [1,2,3] is [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

Here is the recursive code that does it:

```
def powerset(array, idx = None): 
    if idx is None: 
        idx = len(array) - 1
    if idx <0: 
        return [[]]
    ele = array[idx]
    subset = powerset(array,idx-1) 
    for i in range(len(subset)): 
        currentSubset = subset[i]
        subset.append(currentSubset + [ele])
    return subset
```

While I do understand what is happening for the most part, my questions are:

1. when we get to the base case idx<0, this means the idx pointer points outside of the array, and we don't want to call array[idx], but my question is- do we return the empty set "[[]]" just as a filler, so that the top recursive call on the recursion stack gets executed next? Otherwise what does this do?
2. This might be a tallish order, but can someone explain with respect to the example [1,2,3] how the recursive call runs?
   Here is my understanding;

- We start with the pointer idx pointing at 3, so ele=3, we then initialise a subset called subset that holds the powerset of [1,2]
- Here is where I am confused, and struggling to see how the code pans out... Do we now go to the next batch of code which is the for loop? Or do we calculate the powerset of [1,2]?

**Following Chepner's suggestion:**

```
def powerset(array):
    return _powerset(array,len(array)-1)

def _powerset(array,index):
    if index <0:
        return [[]]
    ele = array[index]
    subset = _powerset(array,index-1)
    for i in range(len(subset)):
        subset.append(subset[i] + [ele])
    return subset
```

Comment: The base case adds the first element in the powerset i.e. `[]`. Also I think you should once try tracing the code with pen and paper or running it with a debugger to see what's happening. This tool can help you https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: If `idx` is never intended to be used by the initial call, I would define a separate recursive helper that is meant to be called by the function. `def powerset(array): return _powerset(array, len(array)-1)`, where `_powerset` is the actually recursive function that *requires* a second argument to set `idx`.

Comment: Every set is a subset of itself, so `S` is always in the powerset of `S`. For the empty set `[]`, that's the *only* element of the power set of the empty set.

Comment: Hi Chepner, thanks for the suggestion. One question, in general when is it better to initiate a separate function for the recursive calls vs. using the main function for the recursive calls?

Comment: Or rather, what are the other reasons for using a separate helper function? Clearly one reason is as per above, but are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `print` to the start and end of a recursive call is a useful way to visualize how it works.

```
def powerset(array, idx=None, indent=0):
    trace = f"{'  '*indent}powerset({array}, {idx})"
    print(f"{trace}...")
    if idx is None:
        idx = len(array)-1
    if idx < 0:
        print(f"{trace} -> [[]]")
        return [[]]
    ele = array[idx]
    subset = powerset(array, idx-1, indent+1)
    for i in range(len(subset)):
        subset.append(subset[i] + [ele])
    print(f"{trace} -> {subset}")
    return subset
```

prints:

```
powerset([1, 2, 3], None)...
  powerset([1, 2, 3], 1)...
    powerset([1, 2, 3], 0)...
      powerset([1, 2, 3], -1)...
      powerset([1, 2, 3], -1) -> [[]]
    powerset([1, 2, 3], 0) -> [[], [1]]
  powerset([1, 2, 3], 1) -> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
powerset([1, 2, 3], None) -> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that `0` and `None` need to be handled differently, which is why you need to use `idx is None` instead of `not idx`!

(edit) Per notes in the comments, one way to avoid the `idx = None` confusion (other than to wrap it in another function layer) is to rework the recursion slightly so that it doesn't need the `idx` variable in the first place.  Rather than passing the full array and a variable indicating what part to iterate through, pass the subset of the array that you want to compute the powerset for.  That makes each recursive call (including the very first one) operate according to the exact same "contract" -- compute the powerset of this list.

```
def powerset(array, indent=0):
    trace = f"{'  '*indent}powerset({array})"
    print(f"{trace}...")
    if array:
        p = powerset(array[:-1], indent+1)
        p.extend([s + [array[-1]] for s in p])
    else:
        p = [[]]
    print(f"{trace} -> {p}")
    return p
```

```
powerset([1, 2, 3])...
  powerset([1, 2])...
    powerset([1])...
      powerset([])...
      powerset([]) -> [[]]
    powerset([1]) -> [[], [1]]
  powerset([1, 2]) -> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
powerset([1, 2, 3]) -> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that the sequence of recursive calls is computing the exact same result at each step, but the input is simpler -- rather than watching `idx` go from `None` to `1` to `0` to `-1` and having to reason about what that means, we see `arr` steadily shrink towards the base case, and then each layer of the stack adding the last element of `arr` to each of the previous call's subsets.

Comment: Thanks Sam, this is so helpful. Just one question, what did yo mean that None and 0 need to be handled differently? I did realise that doing 'if not idx:' DOES NOT work for the first line of the code.

Comment: Also Sam, I can see that powerset([1,2,3],1) and powerset([1,2,3],0) and powerset([1,2,3],-1) get put on the recursion stack, well powerset([1,2,3],-1) causes the base case to execute. But what I don't get is how do we then reach ele=3??? Because powerset([1,2,3],1) contains ele=2 and powerset([1,2,3],0) contains ele=1

Comment: And so when we unwind the recursive calls, we get ele=1,2 processed, but how do we get to ele = 3? Because the first recursive call we put on the stack is powerset([1,2,3],1) right?

Comment: The `None` call sets `idx = 2` within its body, which is how you get `ele = 3`.  (yes, this is confusing -- chepner's suggestion of using a helper function would eliminate that confusion.)

Comment: Thanks Sam, I do see that the None call sets idx=2, and ele=3. My only (and still) confusion is when is this called? But I will go with Chepner's suggestion- just on question, when is it a good idea to split out into a separate function for the recursion? Often I see in code people using the same/main function to do the recursive call, while during other time, like Chepner suggested above they use a separate function for the recursion calls.

Comment: If there's a piece of "setup" that you need to do on the first call (in this case setting `idx`), I think it's better to have that in its own function, and then do the rest of the work in a recursive helper.  That way you separate the recursive logic from the setup logic, and it makes each function easier to read and reason about.  This is by no means an ironclad rule and people are free to write code that's briefer and more confusing if they want to.  :)  Not all recursive functions need that extra piece of state though; there's no point adding an extra layer if it's not going to do anything.

Comment: Added to my answer to indicate how you could solve this particular problem without needing that `idx` state at all (which is another way of resolving the confusion around it without needing a helper function).  Having a recursive function reduce the input as it goes down the stack is a very common pattern and is what makes recursion such a powerful tool; it reduces the problem to a combination of solving the smallest/simplest case and expressing more complex cases as increments over decreasingly complex cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam, it is much clearer now to me. With recursion, I've always had this fear that somewhere down the line something won't go as planned, so I've preferred iterative solutions, but given its significance/simplicity and necessity in some cases I will continue learning it.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the function returns the power set of `array[:idx+1]` if it's passed an explicit index.

The test `idx < 0` is really testing `idx == -1`, as other negative values should never occur. In this case, the function should compute the power set of the empty set, which is a set that contains one element: the empty set. The set containing the empty set is represented by `[[]]`.

My impression is that you're trying to think of the recursive function as a loop written in a confusing way. You should instead just think of it as a function that computes something – in this case, a power set – and happens to use itself as a library function (in a way that always terminates).

Given a nonempty set S, which contains an element x, and a way to compute the power set of the smaller set S\{x}, how do you get the power set of S? Answer: for each set in the power set of S\{x}, return two sets: that set, and that set with x added to it. That's what this code does.